# Under USB-hub the USB_DEVICE_DETACHED broadcast event fired not on all detaching devices

Tags: android, usb

I write an app which uses three hardware USB-devices.
When I operate with any single device - both events (USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED/USB_DEVICE_DETACHED) fires normally. Not matter how I bind the Receiver - under the manual registration in the code or in the manifest. And not matter how this single device attached - under the HUB or directly to the device.
The problem is: when I connect three device all in one time (by connecting the filled HUB), USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED event fired for all three devices - I receive notification via onNewIntent callback (or standalone Receiver binded via manifest), and do the permission-approve trip.
But on physical removal all devices behind the HUB (by detaching the HUB itself) DETACH event fires **not on all devices**. It may fired on random single device, or random two devices. But never on all three devices.

As result, for the time UsbManager holds a lot of dead dev-handles of not physically connected devices. At the same time, when I look into /dev/usb/ folder in connecion/disconnection time, device-files appears and removes correctly. As next result, when app is restarted by the some reason, I can not recognize which device is dead and which device is physically present.

The device is ASUS P1801 tablet, OS 4.2.1 
As I can see, it is the last firmware from asus (JOP40D.US_epad-10.6.1.22.5-20130715)

For caching purposes, handles of the wrapped-device I pin to the Application singleton (when device appears with the USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED event or app initialisation):

```
public class HWMountReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Application.getAppContext().isAppReady() && (Application.getAppContext() != null) && (Application.getAppContext().getUsbHWManager() != null)) {
            UsbDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            Application.getAppContext().getUsbHWManager().refreshDevice(device);
            PendingIntent mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Application.getAppContext(), 0, new Intent(Application.MED_ONLINE_DEVICE_PERMISSION), 0);
            ((UsbManager) Application.getAppContext().getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE)).requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

The singleton:

```
private static FirstDevice firstDevice;
private static SecondDevice secondDevice;
private static ThirdDevice thirdDevice;

public void refreshDevice(UsbDevice device) {
    HWDevice dev = HWDevicesFactory.newInstance(device);
    if (dev instanceof FirstDevice) {
        firstDevice = (FirstDevice) dev;
    } else if (dev instanceof SecondDevice) {
        secondDevice = (SecondDevice) dev;
    } else if (dev instanceof ThirdDevice) {
        thirdDevice = (ThirdDevice) dev;
    }
}
```

Factory do reInstantination of each device-wrapper:

```
public static HWDevice newInstance(final UsbDevice device) {
    int vendorId = device.getVendorId();
    int productId = device.getProductId();
    if ((vendorId == FIRST_VENDOR_ID) && (productId == FIRST_PRODUCT_ID)) {
        return new FirstDevice(device);
        ...
```

Device-Wrapper more specific, because each one is very different. But typicaly it contain cached handles on UsbInterface, UsbDeviceConnection, UsbEndpoints and finally UsbDevice itself.

The main thing - DETACH not fired on random device. Not matter how it was "wrapped" by mine

Is there a probably bug in the ASUS firmware,

-or-

I miss some necessary steps/checks with the device connection

-or-
?

Comment: Just came across your question, and I am seeing something remotely similar. I have an app that uses a single USB device. When it disconnects, in some cases `USB_DEVICE_DETACHED` fires, in others it does not. I suspect the broadcast is not always sent reliably. OnePlusOne running LineageOS 15.1 here.

Comment: I think USB subsystem holded by the Android is completely unstable/unusable. For production purposes, seems NDK-wrapping for external devices communication is the way to go.